# VueJs run watcher handler immediatly after triggering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

Example:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            data1: 1,
            data2: 2
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.data1 = 2
        console.log(this.data2)
    },
    watch: {
        data1: {
            handler(newData1) {
                this.data2 = newData1 * 3
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Expected behavior: the browser write number 6 to the console

Current behavior: the browser write number 2 to the console

In this example I try to write the modified data2 after changed data1 value, but it write the data2 value before the watcher handler modify it. Is there a way to immediatly run watcher handler after triggering? I know I can use a computed property in this example but I need data in my project.

I tried to set the watcher immediatly property to true but isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Current behavior: the browser write number 2 to the console

It becauses [Vue performs DOM updates asynchronously](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue) first run into mounted you made change to **data1** (also puts `console.log(this.data2)` to [callback queue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) at this point of time `this.data2 = 2` thats why you see log 2) it also triggers **watch** of **data1** If you log **data2** here you see value of 6.

> In order to wait until Vue.js has finished updating the DOM after a data change, you can use **Vue.nextTick(callback)** immediately after the data is changed

```js
mounted() {
  this.data1 = 2
  this.$nextTick(() => {
     console.log(this.data2); // 6
  })
}
```

or use `Vue.$watch` - Watch an expression or a computed function on the Vue instance for changes

```
data() {
  return {
    data1: 1,
    data2: 2
  }
},
watch: {
  data1: function(val) {
    this.data2 = val * 3
  }
},
mounted() {
  this.data1 = 2
  this.$watch('data2', (newVal) => {
    console.log(newVal) // 6
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can use computed property for **data2**

```
export default {
            data() {
                return {
                    data1: 1
                }
            },
            mounted() {
                this.data1 = 2
                console.log(this.data2)
            },
            computed: {
              data2() {
                return this.data1 * 3 
              }
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

The watcher will not trigger in the middle of your `mounted()` handler, you need to wait until the handler has finished. This is how Javascript works, it is not a limitation in Vue.

Comment: It's not applicable here, immediate additionally triggers a watcher on component instantiation even if there's no `this.data1 = 2`, it won't change how the watcher behaves in this case

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the purpose of your code, but below will work

```
  mounted() {
    this.data1 = 2
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      console.log(this.data2)
    })
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

As [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75292495/3731501) explains, this is expected default behaviour and can be addressed by using `nextTick`, most times it's not the case because a computed is used instead, as suggested in [yet another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75293627/3731501).

In Vue 3, this can be changed by the use of [`flush` option](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#callback-flush-timing):

```
mounted() {
    this.data1 = 2
    console.log(this.data2) // 6
},
watch: {
    data1: {
        handler(newData1) {
            this.data2 = newData1 * 3
        },
        flush: 'sync'
    }
}
```